# localeCompare not detecting whole number when sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Im using JS and jQuery to sort my table and this is my code for sorting table

```
function sortTable(table, column, order) {
        var asc = order === 'asc';
        var tbody = table.find('tbody');

        tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
            if (asc) {
                return $('td:eq(' + column + ')', a).text()
                    .localeCompare($('td:eq(' + column + ')', b).text());
            } else {
                return $('td:eq(' + column + ')', b).text()
                    .localeCompare($('td:eq(' + column + ')', a).text());
            }
        }).appendTo(tbody); 
    }
```

The problem is that the table is sorted only by first number like this:

```
[ 1, 10, 12, 18, 2, 3, 33, 4, 5]
```

and I want it to be like this

```
[ 1, 2 , 3, 4, 5, 10, 12, 18, 33]
```

Comment: You don't need `localeCompare` to sort numbers. Just use `parseInt` on the values and sort it as usual.

Comment: Do you have any example how to implement that to my function?

Comment: @Nemanja, hmm, but what if the string is a combination of numbers and non-numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is treated as sting if you want to treat as number make changes for that column, suppose `column` is `1`, Or if you have multiple numeric column then you can check it in array, lets say if is for `var check_col = [1,2,5];`

```
 tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
        if (asc) {
            if(column==1){ // if check_col.indexOf(column) > -1 for multiple numeric column
               return parseInt($('td:eq(' + column + ')', a).text()) - parseInt($('td:eq(' + column + ')', b).text());
            }else{
               return $('td:eq(' + column + ')', a).text()
                .localeCompare($('td:eq(' + column + ')', b).text());
            }
        } else {
            if(column==1){ // if check_col.indexOf(column) > -1 for multiple numeric column
               return parseInt($('td:eq(' + column + ')', b).text()) - parseInt($('td:eq(' + column + ')', a).text());
            }else{
               return $('td:eq(' + column + ')', b).text()
                .localeCompare($('td:eq(' + column + ')', a).text());
            }
        }
    }).appendTo(tbody);
```

Answer (score 16):

There is an options object that can be provided to the localeCompare method. One of its options is assumed to indicate you can compare numbers as well ('1' < '2' < '10').
Basic usage looks like this:

```
a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {numeric: true})
```

Your code can be modified in this way

```
function sortTable(table, column, order) {
        var asc = order === 'asc';
        var tbody = table.find('tbody');

        tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
            if (asc) {
                return $('td:eq(' + column + ')', a).text()
                    .localeCompare($('td:eq(' + column + ')', b).text(), 'en', {numeric: true});
            } else {
                return $('td:eq(' + column + ')', b).text()
                    .localeCompare($('td:eq(' + column + ')', a).text(), 'en', {numeric: true});
            }
        }).appendTo(tbody); 
    }
```

Check the links to find out possible options for the localeCompare method:

[Intl.Collator() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator)

[String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are sorting numbers as strings. You are doing this:

```
arr = [ 1, 5, 10, 12, 18, 2, 3, 33, 4];

arr.sort((a,b) => {
        return a.toString().localeCompare(b.toString());
      });
//[ 1, 10, 12, 18, 2, 3, 33, 4, 5 ]
```

and you should do something like:

```
arr.sort((a,b) => {
        return a>b;
      });
//[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 12, 18, 33 ]
```

So you could cast `$(whatever).text()` to int adding **+** like `+$(whatever).text()` or using `parseInt()`

if these are numbers `$('td:eq(' + column + ')', a).text()` you could perform something like:

```
function sortTable(table, column, order) {
        var asc = order === 'asc';
        var tbody = table.find('tbody');

        tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
            if (asc) {
                return parseInt($('td:eq(' + column + ')', a).text())>parseInt($('td:eq(' + column + ')', b).text());
            } else {
                return parseInt($('td:eq(' + column + ')', b).text())
                    <parseInt($('td:eq(' + column + ')', a).text());
            }
        }).appendTo(tbody); 
    }
```

Comment: When i change it like you said, then it sorts only first 2 rows. But it needs to scan whole table not only first two rows.

Comment: var arr is an example, could be huge, it's the same

Comment: Are these numbers $('td:eq(' + column + ')', a).text() ?

Comment: yes they are. I found the answer. The problem was that it was treated as string not number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am not giving direct answer but it will your issue 
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/gxFGN/6/)

```
var stringArr = [10,"20",null,"1","bar","-2",-3,null,5,"foo"];


stringArr.sort(sortByDataString); 

function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

// String sorting function
function sortByDataString(a, b) {
    if (a === null) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (b === null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (isNumber(a) && isNumber(b)) {
        if (parseInt(a,10) === parseInt(b,10)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return parseInt(a,10) > parseInt(b,10) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    if (isNumber(a)) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (isNumber(b)) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a === b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return a > b ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: But how can I implement this into my function?

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortTable(table, column, order) {
    var asc = order === 'asc';
    var tbody = table.find('tbody');

    tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
        if (asc) {
             return parseInt($('td:eq(' + column + ')', a).text()) - parseInt($('td:eq(' + column + ')', b).text());
        } else {
            return parseInt($('td:eq(' + column + ')', b).text()) - parseInt($('td:eq(' + column + ')', a).text());
        }
    }).appendTo(tbody); 
}
```